# Broadcasting boolean operations in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have an NxM boolean dataframe X and an Nx1 boolean dataframe Y. I would like to perform a boolean operation on each column returning a new dataframe that is NxM. For example:

```
x = pd.DataFrame([[True, True, True], [True, False, True], [False, False, True]])
y = pd.DataFrame([[False], [True], [True]])
```

I would like x & y to return:

```
       0    1   2
0     False False False
1     True  False True
2     False False True
```

But instead it returns:

```
    0   1   2
0   False   NaN NaN
1   True    NaN NaN
2   False   NaN NaN
```

Instead treating y as a series with
   x & y[0]
gives:

```
    0   1   2
0   False   True    True
1   False   False   True
2   False   False   True
```

Which appears to be broadcasting by row. Is there a correct way to do this other than transposing applying the operation with the Series and than untransposing?

```
(x.T & y[0]).T


    0   1   2 
0   False   False   False
1   True    False   True
2   False   False   True
```

It seems that that fails when the row index is not the same as the column labels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call `apply` and pass a lambda and call `squeeze` to flatten the Series into a 1-D array:

```
In [152]:
x.apply(lambda s: s & y.squeeze())

Out[152]:
       0      1      2
0  False  False  False
1   True  False   True
2  False  False   True
```

I'm not sure if this is quicker though, here we're applying the mask column-wise by calling `apply` on the df which is why transposing is unnecessary

Actually you could use [`np.logical_and`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html):

```
In [156]:
np.logical_and(x,y)

Out[156]:
       0      1      2
0  False  False  False
1   True  False   True
2  False  False   True
```

Comment: np.logical_and seems great for this. Thanks!